# Строковая переменная в условии Select'a

Tags: php, select, mysql

Всем привет!

Есть проблема со вставкой переменной в условие запроса Select.
Есть переменная похожего типа:

```
$qwhere = "id=2 OR id=3 OR id=4 OR id=7";
```

И запрос:

```
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `e1` WHERE status='0' AND ('$qwhere')") or die(mysql_error());
```

В итоге запрос не работает, ошибок не выдает, просто нулевой результат, причем если вставить строку прямо в запрос (без переменной), все работает. В чем может быть проблема?

Предрекаю вопрос "А зачем?":
заранее неизвестно, сколько условий id будет в условии, поэтому пришлось прикрутить костыль - условие собирается чуть выше в виде строки.

Answer (score 0):

Теперь смотри, какой у тебя запрос в итоге получается:

```
SELECT * FROM `e1` WHERE status='0' AND ('id=2 OR id=3 OR id=4 OR id=7')
```

А должен быть (внимание на кавычки):

```
SELECT * FROM `e1` WHERE status='0' AND (id=2 OR id=3 OR id=4 OR id=7)
```

---

Т.е. правильная строка с запросом должна выглядеть вот так:

```
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `e1` WHERE status='0' AND ($qwhere)");
```

А вот так еще правильнее:

```
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `e1` WHERE status='0' AND ({$qwhere})");
```

Но а вообще, мое сугубо личное мнение, лучше так:

```
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `e1` WHERE status='0' AND (" . $qwhere . ")");
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPD: Опоздал я немного :)**

```
SELECT * FROM `e1` WHERE status = '0' AND ($qwhere)
```

И всё заработало :)

Answer (score 0):

> В итоге запрос не работает, ошибок не выдает, просто нулевой результат, причем если вставить строку прямо в запрос (без переменной), все работает. В чем может быть проблема?

В том, что в запрос это вставляется как строка. Получается не "где статус равен нулю и айди равен 2 или айди равен 3 или...", а "где статус равен нулю, а еще строка 'id=2 OR id=3 OR id=4 OR id=7'". Если убрать кавычки, то все заработает. Но вообще это никуда не годится, потому что такое условие выглядит вот так и только так:

```
id IN (2, 3, 4, 7)
```